# How to repair bazaar popup menu icons?

Tags: bazaar, shell-icons

I recently upgraded **bazaar** from 2.5.x beta **to official 2.5.0**, but now the icons of the TortoizeBzr popup menu are not visible.
[image: bazaar popup menu icons issue]

I tried to :

- uninstall / reinstall v2.5.0
- uninstall, reinstall a old version (v2.5.x beta)
- pray for my icons back !

  ... but nothing work here.

**Does anyone have an idea to fix these icons ?**
note1: The same installation on another PC (same OS) do not have this issue.
note2: I'm using tortoizeBzr on WinXP-SP3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's going on here either, but this sounds like a bug to me. You might want to just file a bug against tortoisebzr in Launchpad.